# MongoDB RockMongo Authentication

Tags: php, mongodb, security, rockmongo

I am using MongoDB with RockMongo and I want to have the authentication activated. How to "turn it on" or activate it in RockMongo?

Comment: Awesome word: authentification! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few settings in `config.php`:

```
//$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_db"] = "MONGO_DATABASE";//default mongo db to connect, works only if mongo_auth=false
//$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_user"] = "MONGO_USERNAME";//mongo authentication user name, works only if mongo_auth=false
//$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_pass"] = "MONGO_PASSWORD";//mongo authentication password, works only if mongo_auth=false
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_auth"] = false;//enable mongo authentication?
```

You can either turn on "mongo authentication" with `$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_auth"] = true`, or set defaults with the other three options.

See also the documentation at http://rockmongo.com/wiki/configuration?lang=en_us#%23%23%23%23+mongo_db+%0D

Answer (score 0):

Rockmongo has some issues with authentication, this fork includes fix for that: https://github.com/myurasov/rockmongo